# Configurable Data Access Layer For Different Databases

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, data-access-layer

I want to build a configurable data access layer for different databases.

We are developing a product (web based application) and the client can choose either MS Access or Sql as backend database.

So, I want to develop a data access layer such that if one client wants to use MS Access as backend then I would use inline queries (dynamic queries) for data access and if another client wants to use Sql as backend then I would use stored procedures for data access.

Please help me designing this kind of architecture and it should be configurable.

Here what I am trying to achieve is having separate layer for Model and DAL; When I call DAL methods from Page it should call with respect to type of database.

Model

- Employee

  - ID
  - Name

DAL

- EmployeeAccessDb (Uses inline queries)

  - GetAll
  - GetByID
  - Insert
  - Update
  - Delete
- EmployeeSqlDb (Uses stored procedures)

  - GetAll
  - GetByID
  - Insert
  - Update
  - Delete

Page

- ObjectDataSource SelectMethod="GetAll" TypeName=" < EmployeeAccessDb / EmployeeSqlDb >"
- Insert
- Update
- Delete

Comment: This is far too broad a question for SO. Id suggest doing some research and then ask specific question related to issues you are having during the implementation phase of your project - preferably with code samples etc.

Comment: I added more information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will involve a considerable amount of work but to get you started here is a  quick approach which you can expand upon:

1. Going to need an enum representing your different providers, i.e SQL, Access etc
2. Class perhaps called DataAccess which in the constructor accepts your provider type:

`public class DataAccess
    {
       private DbProviderFactory factory;
       private DbConnection connection;`

```
   public enum Provider
   { SQL, Access } 

   public DataAccess(Provider provider)
   {
        switch (provider)
        {
            case Provider.Ole:
                factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");
                break;
            case Provider.Sql:
                factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");
                break;
        }
        this.connection = factory.CreateConnection();
   }

    public DbDataReader GetDataReader(string statement, params DbParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (DbCommand command = factory.CreateCommand())
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
            command.CommandText = statement;
            command.Connection = connection;
            parameters.ToList().ForEach(x => command.Parameters.Add(x));

            return command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to create a command or parameter etc you use the factory variable.

```
        DbCommand command = Factory.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = procedureName;
        command.Connection = connection;
```

If you want more specific custom code for Access then you would need to go by the inheritance model but I imagine SQL and Access have common syntax, i.e. same SELECT, INSERT commands etc?

Comment: I do not want to have inline queries for client who want sql database as backend, I want to use stored procedures.